# Denoising Prior to Image Classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-classification, computer-vision, noise

From what I have read, Denoising during preprocessing for image classification tasks seems to be a bit controversial.

While on one hand it might improve classification accuracy, the computational complexity seems to discourage a lot of people. Rather I've seen a lot of claims, but hardly anything I can call concrete evidence, which argue that noise "would not matter" for a sufficiently deep neural network.

That being said, assuming that I have decided to perform some kind of Denoising on my data, prior to classification, I'd like to ask what are some good practices?

I've recently gotten into auto-encoders (and their potential in denoising) and I've seen models which either derive features from encodings (in deeper layers) or concatenate encoded features on top of the original data. So essentially, one approach is to embed the "denoiser" into the classification network itself.

Are there any other techniques I can look into? I'm asking in general, so feel free to answer on any other ML models which aren't neural network-based. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any more information about this topic? Also interested.

Comment: @zr0gravity7 not much luck sadly, I guess this is just one of those problems we leave to "industry secrets" :/

Comment: I think another approach to note is simply making the image more robust to noise. If the noisiness is similar in the training dataset than the test dataset (namely there is an inherent noise to the distribution of the real data), then simply making the model more robust to noise may make it perform better on noisy samples. I am not sure how to accomplish this, maybe with data augmentation.

Comment: That's one thing that helps, but it's a lot better when you're working with non-sequential data (namely images). And modern AI being computer-vision-centric, this is advertised as on of the go-to solutions: Add noise yourself, and train the model to learn the same task under the expanded domain which includes noisy samples